# XHTML 2.0 Vs HTML 5

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml2

#### Duplicate:

> - [Why are (X)HTML 5 and XHTML 2 separate standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472274/why-are-xhtml-5-and-xhtml-2-separate-standards)
> - [HTML 5 versus XHTML 1.0 Transitional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256953/html-5-versus-xhtml-1-0-transitional)
> - [HTML vs XHTML does it still matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413114/html-vs-xhtml-does-it-still-matter)

---

There appears to be a unified opinion that the developments in HTML 5 and support by browser vendors of HTML 5, make the adoption of XHTML 1.0 with hopes of the day of XHTML 2.0 a bad choice.

For this reason I have decided for my most recent project to use a strict HTML 4.01 doctype, which has required me to look back at HTML conventions such as not using greater than characters at the end of self closing tags

The question is am I doing the right thing?

Comment: The XHTML vs. HTML debate has come up numerous times - as can be seen in the 'Related' column to the right, most recently, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867498/at-the-end-of-the-day-why-choose-xhtml-over-html  The crux of the issue still comes back to XHTML vs. HTML.  There is far from universal adoption of HTML5 at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is also far from universal adoption of XHTML ;)

Comment: True enough.  So if neither is very well adopted, the issue just comes back to taking them at their theoretical merits? ;)

Comment: Or accepting that web development does, and will probably always, suck. And just go for the lowest common denominator. Which unfortunately, probably means HTML4.01. Or my preferred strategy, just staying the hell away from web programming when at all possible. ;)

Comment: There is that option, too ;)  I still like to hold some hope of the web actually becoming more structured and machine-readable, though... not that I think the XHTML spec is well written at all, but it has some good ideas.

Answer (score 4):

XHTML 2 is going to die a quiet death, unused and unmourned.

Comment: XHTML 2 had some nice stuff. It's too bad that it had to die. Especially considering how HTML 5 didn't fix any of the problems I was waiting for XHTML 2 to fix. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with XHTML, HTML 5 supports most XHTML syntax (`<br />`, etc.)

Comment: And yet still does not have a DTD.