# XHTML or HTML 5 for php application

Tags: xhtml, html

I am in a bit of a dilemma: I know XHTML 1.0 really well and HTML really well. But what markup language should I use in my latest PHP application? XHTML 1.0 or HTML5?

Also which would be future proof?

And finally if I was to build a normal site, what language would be best to use now?

Comment: Duplicate of a dozen other questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872336/xhtml-2-0-vs-html-5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256953/html-5-versus-xhtml-1-0-transitional, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472274/why-are-xhtml-5-and-xhtml-2-separate-standards, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413114/html-vs-xhtml-does-it-still-matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being, I would advise you to stick to HTML 4 (and not XHTML).

As mentioned, if HTML5 is the future way to go, it is not supported enough for now.

Regarding XHTML vs HTML, this is a bit a trollish subject, but I do agree with [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/html-validation-does-it-matter/) and [James Bennet](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/jun/18/html/) that XHTML is just not worth its pain.

Answer (score 2):

XHTML is nice, but it's really only practical as the output of some sort of XML-based process. Stick to HTML 5 for now.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to HTML 4.

In most cases, generating HTML Compatible XHTML is more trouble than it is worth, while HTML 5 is still subject to change and the new features in it are poorly supported.